# Accessing id From a Route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with mongo in laravel with jenssegers
and I want to `$match` with the current id in this function inside my controller:

```
public function updatearray(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);
    # return var_dump($id); 
    # return object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#179 (1) 
    # { ["oid"]=> string(24)"594dd6ccbb7de924c0005585" }
    $result = Work::raw(function($collection) {
        return $collection->aggregate(
            array(
                array('$match' => array( "_id" => $id )),
                array('$project' =>
                    array( "Monto" => array('$sum' => '$Abonos.Monto') )
                )
            )
        );
    });
}
```

And I get.

> (1/1) ErrorExceptionUndefined variable: **id**.

But if I return `$id` before the code enter to the **raw** function it return the proper current id. If I hardcore the `ObjectId` inside the raw query it works.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are confusing the issue. The query is not the problem, but it's your route configuration. This question should only talk about the route and the `$id` not being defined as it comes in. As such, you should be including any controller and route configuration in this question. And really, that's all that needs to be in this question. Separate the concerns.

Comment: I dont really undestand the route problem. Its a fact that the proper id is inside the `updatearray` function, if i `return $id` that show me the id. But the id dont enter to the **raw**.function inside `updatearray`.

Comment: Where are you logging the `$id` value? Show the code above that is actually logging this. If it's visible inside this function then you are duplicating your own question.

Answer (score 1):

> ErrorExceptionUndefined variable: id

because you aren't passing the id to the closure

```
public function updatearray(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);
    $result = Work::raw(function($collection) use ($id) {
        return $collection->aggregate(
            array(
                array('$match' => array( "_id" => $id )),
                array('$project' =>
                    array( "Monto" => array('$sum' => '$Abonos.Monto') )
                )
            )
        );
    });
}
```